# Tensorflow 1.4 numpy incompatibility future warning

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have installed tensorflow 1.4 from conda with python 3.7.7  and numpy 1.18.1.

The instruction I used is the following

```
conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow=1.14
```

When I import tensorflow I get a lot of FutureWarning because i guess the version of numpy used for tensorflow is not the latest, can I remove all the warnings?

The messages are like this:

```
FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
```

Comment: This is surely mismatch in the numpy version allowed for TF1.4. When pip binaries are developed, then will use certain version of different sub libraries. Why do you want very old version of TF when you have best performing recent version TF1.15.2 and TF2.2.

Comment: I solved by installing numpy 1.16.4: conda install -n  numpy=1.16.4

Comment: @VishnuvardhanJanapati yes I know that is very old, I have to use this version for a course

Comment: Post it in as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a mismatch between tensorflow 1.4 and numpy 1.18.1.

To solve the issue you just need to install numpy 1.16.4, for instance:

```
 conda install numpy=1.16.4
```

Comment: You can also suppress warning via a coding in cases you insist on keeping the version. Not recommended though. The best way is what you posted as to install compatible versions.